# merge two array column and keep the distinct in BigQuery

Tags: arrays, merge, google-bigquery

I have a query output like that. I want to have N3 column is the distinct merge of N1 and N2.
[Query output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5J2qA.png)

My current query is this:

```
SELECT  rd.cId  
        , rd.dId 
        ,ARRAY_AGG(ei.IncentiveName IGNORE NULLS) AS N1
        ,ARRAY_AGG(ai.IncentiveName IGNORE NULLS) AS N2

FROM rd
join ei on...
join ai on ...
GROUP BY rd.cId, rd.dId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the problem, in many of the records, there was null value in 2nd column which was returning overall outcome as null.

Fixed that by checking with help of IFNull(N1, []) which solved the problem.

```
SELECT  rd.cId  
    , rd.dId 
    ARRAY_CONCAT(
           IFNULL(ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT ei.IncentiveName IGNORE NULLS),[]),
           IFNULL(ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT ai.IncentiveName IGNORE NULLS),[])
    )
FROM rd
join ei on...
join ai on ...
GROUP BY rd.cId, rd.dId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge both arrays with `array_concat`. Then `unnest` the array and regroup to an arrray, but keep only `distinct` elements.

```sql
with tbl as 
(select 1 id, [1,2,2,3] N1, [1,5,7,8] N2
union all select 2 ,[],[5,5,5,6])

select *,
array_concat(N1,N2),
(select array_agg(distinct x) from unnest(array_concat(N1,N2))x)
from tbl
```

In case you want to group by `id` column:

```sql
with tbl as 
(select 1 id, [1,2,2,3] N1, [1,5,7,8] N2
union all select 2 ,[],[5,5,5,6]
union all select 2 ,[7,8],[9]),

helper as (
  select id, array_agg(N1_) N1, array_agg(N2_) N2
  from tbl,unnest(N1) N1_,unnest(N2) N2_
  group by 1
)
select *,
#array_concat(N1,N2),
(select array_agg(distinct x) from unnest(array_concat(N1,N2))x)
from helper
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below

```
with your_current_query as (
  SELECT  rd.cId  
    , rd.dId 
    ,ARRAY_AGG(ei.IncentiveName IGNORE NULLS) AS N1
    ,ARRAY_AGG(ai.IncentiveName IGNORE NULLS) AS N2
  FROM rd
  join ei on...
  join ai on ...
  GROUP BY rd.cId, rd.dId
)
select *, array(
    select * from t.N1 union distinct
    select * from t.N2
  ) as N3
from your_current_query  t
```